# Clearing SQL server log file LDF

Tags: sql-server-2008

I understand I need to fully backup the log file before I do anything.

But, once I do that, what would happen if I followed the procedure for detaching the database and then deleting the log file and then recreating it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be quick way of shrinking database log file because sp_attach_db will automatically create a new log file of the original size specified with the database creation.
And also detach procedure is safe as SQL Server ensure that server is cleanly detaching database files which means
1. No incomplete transactions are in the database
2. Memory has no dirty pages for DB

Answer (score 0):

After I ran the transaction log backup twice and ran the shrink command all is good in the world.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Once you delete and recreate the log file, it will create the t-log from no knowledge of the DB state and you may encounter data lost.